# Raspberry Pi stopped communicating with i2c sensor

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, gpio, i2c

I am using the CCS811 Gas Sensor with a Pi 3 Model b. I followed the steps on this page https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/raspberry-pi-wiring-and-test and it ran without issue during the burn in period. Now I am getting the error below.

I know the sensor works because I tested it with my Arduino Uno and I can get the readings. On my Pi it shows the correct address of the sensor when I run sudo i2cdetect -y 1.

I have wiped the SD card 3 times now and started over on a clean slate all to end up with this error each time. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here is the code that I am using to read the data from the sensor:

```
ccs = Adafruit_CCS811()

while not ccs.available():
    pass
temp = ccs.calculateTemperature()
ccs.tempOffset = temp - 25.0

while(1):
     if ccs.available():
         temp = ccs.calculateTemperature()
         if not ccs.readData():
           print "CO2: ", ccs.geteCO2(), "ppm, TVOC: ", ccs.getTVOC(), "temp: ", temp
else:
  print "ERROR!"
  while(1):
    pass
sleep(2)
```

Here is the error I am getting

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Adafruit_CCS811_python/examples$ sudo python CCS811_example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "CCS811_example.py", line 6, in <module>
ccs =  Adafruit_CCS811()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_CCS811/Adafruit_CCS811.py", line 84, in __init__
raise Exception("Device ID returned is not correct! Please check your wiring.")
Exception: Device ID returned is not correct! Please check your wiring.
```

[image of wiring and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Pi0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This sensor is not well supported on Raspberry Pi. This is because it uses I2C clock stretching which the Pi cannot do without drastically slowing down the I2C speed. CircuitPython and Arduino are supported.

Quote from:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/overview

AMS recommends that you run this sensor for 48 hours when you first receive it to "burn it in", and then 20 minutes in the desired mode every time the sensor is in use. This is because the sensitivity levels of the sensor will change during early use.

Quote from:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ccs811-air-quality-sensor/overview

Comment: Thanks for the help! Looks like I will be doing this project on my arduino instead!

Comment: PS - The Orange Pi boards (AllWinner SoCs) also work fine reading this sensor without I2C errors. You can try my C code as well - https://github.com/bitbank2/CCS811

Answer (score 0):

This instruction helped me https://learn.adafruit.com/circuitpython-on-raspberrypi-linux/i2c-clock-stretching. Try to do this